# Downloaded pdf file unable to be opened - improper encoding?

Tags: php, file, encoding

I'm unsure how to approach solving this problem. I have a link that when clicked downloads the file to the users machine. The file is a pdf. If I copy and paste the file onto the desktop and then open that copy, it works perfectly fine. Yet when the user downloads and tries to open, I get this:

[image]

Here is the code:(fyi: i have validation on the filename before this..)

```
$file_name = $dat->filename; //'file.avi';
    $file_url = $dat->path . $dat->url . $filename; 
    header('Content-Type:'. $dat->type);
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"");
    header("filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"");
    readfile($file_url);
    exit;
```

I have tried multiple headers but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong with this encoding? Seems to me that the file is valid and should be a simple copy to the users machine just like the copy I made locally worked just fine.

### Update

I opened the file as per Marcin's suggestion, in Sublime. This is what I get.. no body?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/jQuery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="/assets/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jQuery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/pdfObject/pdfObject.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .pdfobject-container {
            height: 99vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
```

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd open the file in i.e. text editor or binary editor and see what's inside. My blind guess you is that you will find there some sort of i.e. PHP notice/error message or something polluting the data other way.

Comment: Ok, I opened it in sumblime and this is what I got:
See my ammended question.. cant fit the code in here

Comment: as I suspected. You are echoing regular HTML page. You may want to open it in webbrowser to see what is shows as I expect some sort of unassigned variable use or something like that which in triggered error handler that produced the html page instead

Comment: ok Ill take a look at the code again.. im clicking a link in one page and loading another with the php code in it.. ah.. i did find something it was not commented out and caused the html to be rendered.. thanks mate! Im sure this will fix it

Comment: Oh no that didnt fix it. File opens now with nothing in it. But downloads just fine.. mime type checked also. that same improperly encoded message shows. im going to try a different approach altogether